# Permission Error. What's wrong?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a guess-the-number game but I keep getting random errors and can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Here's the script:

```
import random
import sys
import os

def guess_number():
    file = open('highscores.txt', 'r+')#opens file
    highscore = file.read()
    highscore = int(highscore)
    name = input('Enter your name: ')

    answer = random.randint(1,100)
    print('Hi ' + name + '! I\'m thinking of a number between 1 and 100!')
    guesses = 0
    while guesses < 100:
        print('Take a Guess! ')
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        if guess < answer:
            print('Your guess was too low!') 
            guesses = guesses + 1
        if guess > answer:
            print('Your guess was too High!')
            guesses = guesses + 1
        if guess == answer:
            guesses = guesses + 1
            break

    if guess == answer:
        answer = str(answer)
        guesses = str(guesses)



        print('Good Job ' + name + '! You guessed ' + answer + ' in ' +     guesses + ' guesses!')
        guesses = int(guesses)
    if highscore > guesses:
        file.close()
        os.remove('highscores.txt')
        file = open('highscores.txt', "w")
        print('Congratulations! You beat the highscore!')
        guesses = str(guesses)
        file.write(guesses)
        file.close()
        guesses = int(guesses)
    elif highscore < guesses:
        highscore = str(highscore)
        print('The highscore is:  ' + highscore)
```

By the way, I have a separate file named `highscores.txt`; when the program first runs I type "100" in the file and save it.

Here's the traceback of the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    guess_number()
  File "C:\Users\rhino_000\Desktop\guesses\guesses.py", line 39, in guess_number
    os.remove('highscores.txt')
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it     is being used by another process: 'highscores.txt'
```

Comment: What errors do you get, please provide the **traceback**.

Comment: "but i keep getting random errors" Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Every comment you write, I write 0.5 seconds later. :)

Comment: It appears to work on and off, sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: @RianO'Hanlon: anyway it is better to always close the file immediately.

Comment: The problem is you're opening a file reference with `file = open('highscores.txt', 'r+')` and not closing it after you're done.

Comment: Have you tried just not doing the os.remove call?  If you open a file in 'w' mode, this will overwrite the old value ('a' will open in append).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that you should close the file before using it again. An easy way to do that in Python is to use the `with` syntax.

```
with open('qwerty.txt', 'r') as f:
     content = f.read()

# File is automatically closed now.
print(content)
```

The problem is most likely that you run the program multiple times consecutively, but the `elif` part does not close the file and the file is not closed on OS level when the program stops. You should always close the file in Python to not get such hangers in the system.

Comment: Can i just use file.close()?

Comment: @RianO'Hanlon Yes, you can, but then you have to add it to every possible path where the program can go. Also you have to consider that when the code exits with an exception and does not reach your `close()`, you still get a hanger in the system jamming your next code-run up. So it is recommended to use the `with` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on makaveli's answer and the comment I posted above. The code below appears to resolve all filesystem access issues. I've tested the game over multiple runs and it appears to work fine.

```
import random


def guess_number():
    with open('highscores.txt', 'r+') as f:
        highscore = int(f.read())

    name = input('Enter your name: ')

    answer = random.randint(1, 100)
    print('Hi ' + name + '! I\'m thinking of a number between 1 and 100!')
    guesses = 0
    while guesses < 100:
        print('Take a Guess! ')
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        if guess < answer:
            print('Your guess was too low!')
            guesses = guesses + 1
        if guess > answer:
            print('Your guess was too High!')
            guesses = guesses + 1
        if guess == answer:
            guesses = guesses + 1
            break

    if guess == answer:
        answer = str(answer)
        guesses = str(guesses)

        print('Good Job ' + name + '! You guessed ' + answer + ' in ' + guesses + ' guesses!')
        guesses = int(guesses)
    if highscore > guesses:
        print('Congratulations! You beat the highscore!')
        with open('highscores.txt', "w") as f:
            guesses = str(guesses)
            f.write(guesses)
    elif highscore < guesses:
        highscore = str(highscore)
        print('The highscore is:  ' + highscore)


guess_number()
```

**Example Run**

Below is an example of one of the test runs I did. Before I ran the test, `highscores.txt` contained 9 (from a previous run) and after the run it contained 6.

```
Enter your name: tagc
Hi tagc! I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100!
Take a Guess! 
50
Your guess was too High!
Take a Guess! 
25
Your guess was too low!
Take a Guess! 
37
Your guess was too low!
Take a Guess! 
44
Your guess was too High!
Take a Guess! 
40
Your guess was too High!
Take a Guess! 
38
Good Job tagc! You guessed 38 in 6 guesses!
Congratulations! You beat the highscore!
```

Comment: -1 for doing it all for him so he won't have to type it all and learn it.
+1 for testing the answer... I was lazy. :)

Comment: @makaveli Couldn't resist. 90% of the reason I fixed it was because I was bored and simple guessing games like these keep me entertained. :)